# Mysql create a column named Rank

Tags: php, mysql

Let me tell you an example from my question.
For example we have table named (order) that insert all orders and purchase to this table.

Table A (orders):

```
+--------------------------+
| CustomerKey | ProductKey |
+--------------------------+
| 306545      | pro1       |
| 597864      | pro3       |
| 784678      | pro2       |
| 905479      | pro3       |
| 306545      | pro1       |
| 348965      | pro3       |
| 784678      | pro3       |
+--------------------------+
```

Now i would like to order and get our Bestselling products
and for example get pro3 rank in bestselling products list
Query output:

```
+-------------------------------+
| id | ProductKey | numberSold  |
+-------------------------------+
| 1  | pro3       | 4           |
| 2  | pro1       | 2           |
| 3  | pro2       | 1           |
+-------------------------------+
```

I wrote i query for this:

```
select ProductKey, count(1) as numberSold from A group by ProductKey order by count(1) desc
```

but it is not complete! this query need to a row named rank (Look at the below query output):

```
+-------------------------------------+
| id | ProductKey | numberSold | rank |
+-------------------------------------|
| 1  | pro3       | 4          | 1    |
| 2  | pro1       | 2          | 2    |
| 3  | pro2       | 1          | 3    |
+------------------------------+------+
```

Comment: What is 'id'???

Comment: @Strawberry id is a unique column

Comment: No it isn't. It appears nowhere in your data set.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SET @counter = 0; 
select ProductKey, count(1),  as numberSold, (@counter := @counter +1) as rank from A group by ProductKey order by count(1) desc
```

Let me also point out that if you are running this query through PHP, then you can do without the rank column in query because when you loop through the results, you can just echo the value of `$counter` variable that starts with 1 and increments by 1 on each iteration.

Comment: Thanks! i wrote this query: `SET @counter = 0; 
select *,ProductKey, count(1) as numberSold, (@counter := @counter +1) as rank from A where DATE(time)=CURDATE() group by ProductKey order by numberSold desc` and i get this outout! : [viewScreenShot](http://up.vbiran.ir/uploads/19471150208801520154_ddddddd.JPG)

Comment: and for example i need have 10000 products and i need to get pro365 rank (like 2441)

Comment: I had tested this on small dataset and it appreared to be working at that time. but you are right it doesnt work the way you want as the ranks are ordered based on the position of productKey and not the numberSold. 

But if you want this on PHP, i can write that function for you.

Comment: @AmirJoshi can you write that function ?

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by background process.
Run a **cronjob** like a process to rank a product.

Comment: how can i do it in cronjob?

Comment: By running the below program in every hour/minute you can update the rank of a product.

<?php

$qry = mysql_query("select id, numberSold product_list order by numberSold desc");

$rank = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)) {
 mysql_query("update product_list set rank='$rank' where id=$row['id'];
 $rank++;
}